# Oracle Primary MMC Snap-In - Not installed correctly

Tags: oracle, windows-7

I have just installed Oracle 11g (32bit) on a Windows 7 (64bit) machine and when I try to start the Administration Assistant, I get the following message:

```
MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.

Name: Oracle Primary MMC Snap-In
CLSID:{50D06DC1-CFFE-11D1-8271-00C04FD945C7}
```

Does anyone have a clue how can I get rid of this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to reinstall Windows and then Oracle to solve this

Comment: This is not a solution.You should re-register oracle COM server components (regsvr32) and check.

Comment: Of course it isn't, but at least it led to a response being provided :)

Comment: rkosegi, I think you could answer the question properly instead of commenting

Comment: I will not place it as "answer" because I have not enough info to consider it as solution.Also look here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/3f00bf30-2d81-4e6c-9bcc-16e06ebf46eb